# CSS transition, collapsing width/height to center of div

Tags: html, css

Below is my effort.

http://liveweave.com/i1qkNw

Below is also my code

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
}
.door {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: .5s;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.container:hover .door {
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="door"></div>

</div>
```

What i want to do is, when user hovers over container, I want the door div's width/height to be zero. As you can see, I am achieving this effect but it disappears to upper left corner. Is there any way I can make it disappear to its center?? Like the width and height are reduced till its center and disappear.

Kindly guide me how to achieve this effect.

Comment: ok i was able to do it via transform:scale command. But then again it doesnt let me change the origin point

Answer (score 1):

You have to set top / bottom / left / right values to `50%`.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
}
.door {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: .5s;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.container:hover .door {
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="door"></div>
</div>
```